# Оптимальное решение для real-time'овского обновления

Tags: android, json, оптимизация, get, request

Всем привет, как правильнее сделать приложении на android которое бы постоянно спрашивало на сайте информацию в формате json при помощи стандартных get запросов? В общем, я правильно думаю или это дело можно как-то сделать по другому, чтоб нагрузка на сайт меньше была?

Comment: а стандартный push не подходит?

Comment: В смысле push ?

Comment: В самом прямом. https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start
В андроиде из-коробки есть нужная Вам функциональность. Только работать нужно по другому - сам сайт, когда понял, что есть новые данные, рассылает всем подписчикам сообщение. (это делается через сервера гугла).
Если же сайт не Ваш (ну всякое бывает), тогда Вам нужен один сервер, который будет дергать раз в какое то время и если есть нужная информация - рассылать подписчикам.

Comment: Не, сайт мой, и как я вас понял надо делать сервер, который будет рассылать инфу подключенным при помощи сокетов к серверу телефонам. Правильно?

Comment: Вам нужно только отправить сообщение на сервера гугла, а они уже все сами сделают. На сервер гугла сообщение можно отправить обычным http запросом - https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http#auth

Comment: @KoVadim а это всё бесплатно ? :D

Comment: да, но есть лимиты. Если нужно будет лимиты увеличить - нужно просто в поддержку написать и попросить. Если с приложением все ок, то скорее всего увеличат без проблем. А заплатить можно в другом месте:) если сильно хочется.

Comment: Ну ладно тогда, на ближайшее время так сделаю, а потом сделаю свой сервер. Оформите это как ответ, чтобы тема считалась закрытой.